# Write OLED driver for RaspberryPi

Tags: linux-kernel, raspberry-pi, driver, led

I am writing a driver module for my 128x64 OLED(ssd1306), which will be used on my raspberry pi. And it works in 4-wire SPI mode. Firstly, I read the datasheet of the ssd1306 and wrote some basic functions. Then I connected  this OLED with an Arduino board, ran the codes to test its correctness and I found it worked quite well. 
Here are my arduino code:

```
//oled.ino
#define clearPin(a) digitalWrite(a, LOW)
#define setPin(a) digitalWrite(a, HIGH)

char* hello = "Hello World!";

// visible ascii chars
const unsigned char F6x8[][6] =
{
  //... 
};
const unsigned char F8X16[]=
{
  //...
};

// pin assignments
int CS = 53;
int DIN = 51;
int CLK = 52;
int DC = 3;
int RES = 2;

//***********************************
int writeCommand(byte command)
{
  int i;
  clearPin(CS);
  clearPin(DC);
  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    clearPin(CLK);
    delay(1);
    if((command >> (7-i)) & 0x1)
      setPin(DIN);
    else
      clearPin(DIN);
    delay(1);
    setPin(CLK);
    delay(1);
  }
  setPin(CS);
}

int writeData(byte data)
{
  int i;
  clearPin(CS);
  setPin(DC);
  for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
  {
    clearPin(CLK);
    delay(1);
    if((data >> (7 - i)) & 0x1)
      setPin(DIN);
    else
      clearPin(DIN);
    delay(1);
    setPin(CLK);
    delay(1);
  }
  setPin(CS);
}

void setPostion(byte x, byte y)
{
    writeCommand(0xB0 | y);    // go to page y
    writeCommand(0x00 | (x & 0x0f)); // setPin lower column address
    writeCommand(0x10 | ((x >> 4) & 0x0f)); // setPin higher column address
}

void write6x8Char(byte x, byte y, char ch)
{
    setPostion(x, y);
    int i, c = ch - 32;
    for(i = 0; i < 6; i++)
    writeData(F6x8[c][i]);
}

void write6x8String(byte x, byte y, char* str)
{
    //...
}

void write8x16Char(byte x, byte y, char ch)
{
    setPostion(x, y);
    int i, c = ch - 32;
    for(i = 0; i < 8; i++)
        writeData(F8X16[c * 16 + i]);
    setPostion(x, y+1);
    for(i = 8; i < 16; i++)
        writeData(F8X16[c * 16 + i]);
}

void write8x16String(byte x, byte y, char* str)
{
    //...
}

void clearScreen()
{
    fill(0);
}

void fill(unsigned char bmp_data)
{
  unsigned char y,x;

  for(y = 0; y < 8; y++)
  {
    writeCommand(0xb0 + y);
    writeCommand(0x00);
    writeCommand(0x10);
    for(x = 0; x < 128; x++)
      writeData(bmp_data);
  }
} 

void setDisplayOn(byte on)
{
  writeCommand(0xAE | on);
}

//***********************************************

void initialize()
{
    setPin(CLK);
    clearPin(RES);
    delay(50);
    setPin(RES);
    setDisplayOn(1);
    fill(0x00);
}

void setup()
{
  pinMode(CS, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DIN, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(CLK, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(DC, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(RES, OUTPUT);
  initialize();
}


void loop()
{
  write8x16String(0, 0, hello);
}
```

So I moved them directly into my driver module file with few necessary changes. Here are my oled.c file and Makefile:

```
//oled.c
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/device.h>
#include <linux/gpio.h>
#include <linux/interrupt.h>
#include <linux/cdev.h>
#include <linux/ioctl.h>
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#define DRIVER_NAME "OLED"
#define DEVICE_NAME "OLED"

#define clearGPIO(a) gpio_set_value(a, 0)
#define setGPIO(a) gpio_set_value(a, 1)

const int DIN = 5;
const int CLK = 6;
const int CS = 13;
const int DC = 19;
const int RES = 26;

const unsigned char F6x8[][6] =
{
    //...
};
const unsigned char F8X16[]=
{
    //...
};

//*****************************************
void delay(int ms)
{
    int i, j;
    for(i = 0; i < ms; i++)
    {
        j = 100000;
        while(j--);
    }
}
//...Same functions with the arduino program... 

//*****************************************

static dev_t oled_devno;
static struct class *oled_class;
static struct cdev oled_dev;
static int flag = 0;

//open
static int oled_open(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    int err;
    printk(KERN_INFO"Initializing GPIOs...\n");
    err = gpio_request_one(CS, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "CS");
    if(err){
        printk(KERN_ERR"[%s %d]:Request led gpio failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        gpio_free(CS);
    }
    err = gpio_request_one(DC, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "DC");
    if(err){
        printk(KERN_ERR"[%s %d]:Request led gpio failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        gpio_free(DC);
    }
    err = gpio_request_one(RES, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "RES");
    if(err){
        printk(KERN_ERR"[%s %d]:Request led gpio failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        gpio_free(RES);
    }
    err = gpio_request_one(DIN, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "DIN");
    if(err){
        printk(KERN_ERR"[%s %d]:Request led gpio failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        gpio_free(DIN);
    }
    err = gpio_request_one(CLK, GPIOF_OUT_INIT_LOW, "CLK");
    if(err){
        printk(KERN_ERR"[%s %d]:Request led gpio failed\n", __func__, __LINE__);
        gpio_free(CLK);
    }
    flag = 1;
    printk(KERN_INFO"Initializing OLED...\n");
    oled_initialize();
    printk(KERN_INFO"OLED open\n");
    return 0;
}

//release
static int oled_release(struct inode *inode, struct file *filp)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        gpio_free(CS);
        gpio_free(DC);
        gpio_free(RES);
        gpio_free(DIN);
        gpio_free(CLK);
    }
    printk(KERN_INFO"OLED release\n");
    return 0;
}

//write
ssize_t oled_write(struct file *filp, char *buf, size_t count, loff_t *f_pos)
{
    char* hello = "Hello driver";
    printk(KERN_INFO"I am writing data!\n");
    write8x16String(0, 0, hello);
    return 0;
}

static struct file_operations oled_fops = {
    .owner = THIS_MODULE,
    .open  = oled_open,
    .release  = oled_release,
    .write = oled_write,
};

static int __init oled_init(void)
{
    int err;

    printk(KERN_INFO"OLED Init \n");

    err = alloc_chrdev_region(&oled_devno,0,1,DRIVER_NAME);   
    if(err < 0){
        goto err;
    }
    cdev_init(&oled_dev,&oled_fops);

    err = cdev_add(&oled_dev,oled_devno,1);

    if(err < 0)
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR"[%s,%d]add cdev failed\n",__func__,__LINE__);
        goto FREE_DEVNO;
    }
    //
    oled_class = class_create(THIS_MODULE,DEVICE_NAME);
    if(IS_ERR(oled_class))
    {
        printk(KERN_ERR"[%s,%d]class create failed\n",__func__,__LINE__);
        goto DEV_FREE;
    }
    device_create(oled_class,NULL,oled_devno,NULL,DEVICE_NAME);

    return 0;
DEV_FREE:
    cdev_del(&oled_dev);
FREE_DEVNO:
    unregister_chrdev_region(oled_devno, 1);
err:
    return err;
}

static void oled_exit(void)
{
    if(flag)
    {
        gpio_free(CS);
        gpio_free(DC);
        gpio_free(RES);
        gpio_free(DIN);
        gpio_free(CLK);
    }
    device_destroy(oled_class,oled_devno);
    class_destroy(oled_class);
    cdev_del(&oled_dev);
    unregister_chrdev_region(oled_devno, 1);
    printk(KERN_INFO"OLED exit\n");
}

module_init(oled_init);
module_exit(oled_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

Makefile:

```
//Makefile
ifneq ($(KERNELRELEASE),)
    obj-m := oled.o
else
    KERNELDIR:=/home/rpi/linux/
    PWD := $(shell pwd)
    CROSS_COMPILE := arm-linux-gnueabihf-
default:
    $(MAKE) CROSS_COMPILE=$(CROSS_COMPILE) ARCH=arm -C $(KERNELDIR) M=$(PWD) modules
clean:
    rm -rf *.o *.ko *.mod.c *.order *.symvers   
endif
```

However, when I wrote a program to open the device and write characters into it, there was no response from this OLED. And no error was logged into kern.log. What I really don't understand is why they behaved differently with the same control functions? Is there something fatal that I ignored?

Comment: Did you check fbtft driver?

Comment: But I didn't use that driver, I just set or cleared the gpio values according to the write procedure in 4-wire Serial interface mode..

Comment: Hey, thanks! I finally find that these codes have no errors at all! It's all because of this OLED! It only accepts 5V as high level  and it can work well without connecting to VCC! What an amazing chip ! I can't believe that I have spent 2 days on it!

Comment: SSD1306 works on 3.2V without problems the problem is it has the same HW bug as ARDUINO SW I2C lib (sending ACK signals once per packet instead of once per BYTE) the LCD is unusable with correct HW/SW I2C implementations (it will freeze the I2C comunication for good) . Had to make my own SW I2C lib just to workaround this issue on AVR32 (took me weeks to analyze what was happening) Also it has no commands for resetting the VRAM address pointer making it unreliable in long therm usage as any transfer corruption will shift the image until VCC power on/off.